# Visual Studio 2013/15 Nuget Errors on Console - "The module to process 'nuget.psm1', listed in field 'ModuleToProcess' of module manifest..."

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, visual-studio-2015

Opening up Nuget Console I receive the following error:

> The following error occurred while loading the extended type data
>   file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(32) : Error in
>   type "System.Xml.XmlNode": Exception: Cannot create a code method
>   because of the method format. The method should be public, static, and
>   have one parameter of type PSObject. The following error occurred
>   while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(44) : Error in
>   type "System.Xml.XmlNodeList": Exception: Cannot create a code method
>   because of the method format. The method should be public, static, and
>   have one parameter of type PSObject. The following error occurred
>   while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(87) : Error in
>   type "System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection": Exception:
>   Cannot create a code method because of the method format. The method
>   should be public, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject. The
>   following error occurred while loading the extended type data file:
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(353) : Error
>   in type "System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry": Exception: Cannot
>   create a code method because of the method format. The method should
>   be public, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject. The
>   following error occurred while loading the extended type data file:
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(360) : Error
>   in type "System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry": Exception: Cannot
>   create a code method because of the method format. The method should
>   be public, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject. The
>   following error occurred while loading the extended type data file:
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(372) : Error
>   in type "System.IO.DirectoryInfo": Exception: The getter method should
>   be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
>   The following error occurred while loading the extended type data
>   file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(399) : Error
>   in type "System.IO.FileInfo": Exception: The getter method should be
>   public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject. The
>   following error occurred while loading the extended type data file:
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2977) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject. The following error occurred while loading
>   the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2984) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject. The following error occurred while loading
>   the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2991) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject. The following error occurred while loading
>   the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2998) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject. The following error occurred while loading
>   the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3005) : Error
>   in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The
>   getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one
>   parameter of type PSObject. The following error occurred while loading
>   the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3219) : Error
>   in type "Microsoft.PowerShell.DeserializingTypeConverter": Type
>   "Microsoft.PowerShell.DeserializingTypeConverter" should be a
>   TypeConverter or an PSTypeConverter. The following error occurred
>   while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3648) : Error
>   in type "System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata":
>   Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and
>   have one parameter of type PSObject. The following error occurred
>   while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3733) : Error
>   in type "System.Management.Automation.FormatViewDefinition":
>   Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and
>   have one parameter of type PSObject. The module to process
>   'nuget.psm1', listed in field 'ModuleToProcess' of module manifest
>   'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\QIYNP3CN.X43\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.psd1' was not processed because no valid module was found in any module
>   directory.

I can update some of the nuget packages but not Entity Framework and some other packages. With the latter I receive an error:

> "...failed to initialize the PowerShell host.  If your PowerShell
>   execution policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the Package Manager
>   Console to initialize the host first."

I should add I have Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This explains how to resolve part of my issue (but no why it had happened):
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b20e64e-e35f-4d0e-91f1-aebcfda7ebf2/package-manager-console-failed-to-load?forum=visualstudiogeneral

So edit devenv.exe.config and add the following (you may not need the "runtime" nor "assemblyBinding" tags but you get the idea:

```
 <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Management.Automation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

Now this resolves my issue of not being able to update NuGet packages. However I still see errors i.e.:

> The following error occurred while loading the extended type data
>   file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(32) : Error in
>   type "System.Xml.XmlNode": Exception: Cannot create a code method
>   because of the method format. The method should be public, static, and
>   have one parameter of type PSObject.

Bottom line I must have screwed up my Windows 8.1 Pro permissions. I was trying to open up links within Visual Studio 2013 into Chrome so I installed Chrome as administrator... the rest is history.

If I had time I would reinstall Windows 8.1 but the aforementioned temp solution is just that... a temp solution.

I found no windows "fix" and no-one appears to have had the same issue.

Hope this sort of helps anyone else.

Comment: Can't believe this, but just had the same issue with Visual Studio 2015! So once again added the same config changes!

Comment: I had it in VS2015 too. Maybe after some PowerShell module installation of Visual Studio plugin.

Comment: Just observed exactly same errors. My solution is pretty simple: I've uninstalled the PowerShell Extensions for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: it seems to happen only on machine with **Insider Preview Build** correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Moes, I see it on regular Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @Moes, I have. Actually it made the problem permanent. So far repairing VS and then adding those binding redirects seems to be working.

Comment: @Rob I do have the same issue on a fully patched Win10 Pro machine.
I tried repairing VS installation, uninstall/reinstall NuGet Package Manager. Nothing helps, so far.

Comment: I had to do this to my local AppData dev config file. Updating the config file next to the exe didn't work. 

Here is the folder path for VS 2015:
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config

Comment: @Andrew C, thanks a lot, I had this problem for more than half a year, from time to time, I tried everything I could find, and repairing VS 2015 or installing VS 2017 didn't change anything, but you did !!

Comment: @AndrewC updating the file `devenv.exe.config` in `LocalAppData` path worked for me using VS2013 Update 5. Full path is `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\devenv.exe.config`