# Visual Studio 2015 - Package Manager Console error

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, nuget, package-managers

When I open the Package Manager Console in VS2015 I am 'greeted' by the following error message:

> The module to process 'nuget.psm1', listed in field 'ModuleToProcess'
>   of module manifest 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\T3SN2KBD.PPE\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.psd1' was not processed because no valid module was found in any module
>   directory.

I've had a browse around and adding stuff to the devenv.exe.config [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333057/visual-studio-2013-15-nuget-errors-on-console-the-module-to-process-nuget-ps/23403397#23403397) did not resolve my problem. Apart from that post I can't really find that much about this error.

There are no pending updates and I have tried reinstalling nuget and the Power Shell Tools for VS2015 (which I did not have installed and only generated more errors in the console window - so I removed it again)

Any input greatly appreciated

**Updates:**

- Checked that file(s) exist and are accessible
- Checked/Updated Execution Policy (CurrentUser and LocalMachine are now Unrestricted)
- Reinstalled NuGet
- This is an issue on Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 on this workstation
- Running Powershell v5.0.10586.122

Comment: Did you checked, whether there is a `NuGet.psm1` and `NuGet.psd1` in `C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\T3SN2KBD.PPE\Modules\NuGet`?

Comment: @jisaak - yep, both files are present, accessible and appear to be intact

Comment: hm, okay. Maybe try to Import the module manuell to see if you get any additional errors using `Import-Module C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\T3SN2KBD.PPE\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.psd1 -Debug`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a prompt in the Package Manager Console

Comment: Just open powershell and try it out, not Visual Studio.

Comment: Tried that - it complains about being the wrong host (Console Host instead of Package Manager Host)

Comment: oh, you are right, sorry, no idea anymore

Comment: Does [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903303/entity-framework-with-nuget-import-module-error-in-init-ps1) help at all?  -edit: If that's not helpful (apologies, that link is for EntityFramework) you might have to resort to using ProcMon to capture what VS is trying to do.

Comment: Not the same issue I'm afraid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I seem to have fixed the issue with help from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638289/embedding-powershell-v2-0-in-net-app-on-windows-8-rtm) - or more accurately one of the comments on the accepted answer.

I had previously seen and tried this solution to no avail but in the comments a user mentions editing the file at `c:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config‌​`

Well that did the trick. Despite adding the lines to the 'main' `devenv.exe.config` they don't seem to have made their way to this 'working?' folder.

Wasted a lot of time on this so I hope this helps the next poor soul to stumble across this issue.